# In PostgreSQL, how can you declare a variadic function that accepts arguments of differing types?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

It's definitely possible to define such a function through the C API as can be witnessed by looking at json_build_array() for example:

[image]

Unfortunately trying to create a SQL or pl/pgSQL function like this fails

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function( VARIADIC _args anyelement[]) RETURNS ...
```

and this is no surprise as the PostgreSQL documentation mentions that 'VARIADIC' only works for arrays (and it seems there is no such thing as an anyelement[]). Does anybody know how to get this working without having to write a C function ?

Comment: Don't have time for full answer. I can point you at [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS). Search for `polymorphic`. That will also lead you to [Polymorphic Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not possibility now. PLpgSQL and SQL languages are out of game, because there are not arrays with fields of different types. And PL/Perl or PL/Python just doesn't support, it what I know.